# "Found ) when expecting ( " Java Script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an if statement to one of my JS Karel functions that will allow me to use just one set on parenthesis; However, every time I leave my if statement with just one set of () i get an error message. I've read my lecture notes as well as my reader regarding the usage and syntax needs of an if loop and in all of its documentation there's no sign of a need for an extra set of parenthesis.

Below I'll make sure to add an example of what actually works.

*** WHAT I WANT TO WORK BUT GIVES ME AN ERROR ***

```
function moveToWall() {

    if (noBeepersPresent) {
       putBeeper();
}

    else (beepersPresent) {
       move();

}

}
```

*** WHAT ACTUALLY WORKS AND DRIVES ME CRAZY, BUT DOESN'T PRODUCE AN ERROR MESSAGE ***

```
function moveToWall() {

    if (noBeepersPresent()) {
       placeBeeper();
}

    else (beepersPresent()) {
       move();

}

}
```

> found ) when expecting (

Comment: `else` shouldn't be followed by a condition. It runs whenever the first condition fails. If you want to check a different condition, use `else if (beepersPresent)`

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these are valid JavaScript.  What you want is `else if`.

```
function moveToWall() {

  if (noBeepersPresent()) {
       placeBeeper();
  } else if (beepersPresent()) {
       move();

  }

}
```

However, in reading your code, it seems that you have actually two ways to determine whether or not beepers are present.  That wouldn't generally be recommended.  Instead, use negation with `!`.

In your code example, you don't even need that second condition.  A regular `if`/`else` would be fine.  If `noBeepersPresent()` were falsy, then `beepersPresent()` would surely return truthy, so there's no reason to check it.